# Определение пунктуационных ошибок в тексте

Tags: пунктуация

Возникли некоторые разногласия с одним замечательным человеком. Предмет спора:

> Дорогие наши, любимые, Светик и Влад!
>   От всей души мы поздравляем Вас
>   с 10-й годовщиной вашей свадьбы!!!
>   Счастья, любви, здоровья, благополучия вам
>   и вашим ангелочкам - Катюше и Сашеньке!
>   С любовью, семья Тарасовых!!!

Для меня пунктуационные ошибки очевидны, но хотелось бы узнать компетентное мнение филолога.

Comment: Я думаю, главную ошибку сделали Вы. Не орфографическую, этикетную. Зачем тут фото с конкретными именами-фамилиями?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что раскрывает личные данные.

Comment: В нашей стране немало семей Тарасовых (к коей я и принадлежу) )

Comment: Это не основания использовать ресурс для публикации личных архивов.

Comment: Ну что за глупости... Моей целью было не публиковать "личные архивы" (Боже мой, как всё брутально =) ), а прояснить вопрос. Если тему удалят, я мужественно переживу это.

Comment: Действительно, при чем тут личные данные? Вопрос касается русского языка. В нем нет ничего оскорбительного. И тем более говорить о этикетной ошибки....

Comment: «Некоторые разногласия с одним замечательным человеком» как предмет спора не представлен на фото. Может в этом проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Дорогие наши, любимые Светик и Влад!"* Однородные определения, отнесенные к обращению.

*"...вашим ангелочкам, Катюше и Сашеньке"*.  Факультативные знаки при обособлении: тире или запятая.

Comment: Vera, благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Тут две ошибки: "любимые" в первом предложении не должны обособляться, а во втором предложении "Вас" должно писаться со строчной, так как это обращение к нескольким лицам.